# Is lord ram depicted of 2 arms or 4 in ram raksha stotra?

Tags: rama

In dhyan mantra of ram raksha.. 1st line says meditate on ajaanubaahu ram(hands long till knees) who's holding arrow & bow. Then second line says baddha padmasanastham.. So is he 4 or 2 armed here as baddha padmasan needs both hands catching feet & at the same time he is holding arrow & bow.. + there's no painting or image based on this dhyan where he's watching ma sita who's sitting on his left thigh & he having matted hairs till his thighs.. So is he 2 or 4 arms here?? + there r bhadrachalam like temples having he 4 arms but yes I know nothing of mentions in text like that.. Please tell your views or solve if u can..[image: baddha padmasan]

Comment: OK.. Your point of view is right! This can be what I am searching for.. As my guru(Maithiliramansharan Lakshman kiladhish) too said there he isn't meant 4 hands. So I am agreeing the point that he isn't meant 4 hands there.. But we just had a chat & he said when I'll be ayodhya he shall explain in details how.. Possibly ram is in baddha padmasan & is told that he is an Archer.. Just the thing confuses is why dhrut shara dhanusham like why bow arrow told separate.. Maybe the holder of arrow & bow is in baddha padmasan. I agree. Just after few days I'll get to know what guru exactly meant

Comment: The idol of Sri Rama (moolavar) has distinctive features. The deity is in the padmasana pose with four hands, (Chaturbuja Rama) holding the bow and arrow in the front two hands, and Sankha and Chakra in the rear hands.....The temple of Lord Rama at Bhadrachalam with the Godavari as the backdrop.

Comment: Yup.. I saw movie on sri ramadasu & read about bhadrachalam & few temples in south because I wanna visit them soon.. :)

Comment: Yup south India has more ram's diverse & awesome temples & I am in love with them.. South India has preserved Hinduism very passionately.. As for eg. Paintings of Shiva compare north Indian & south.. South ones take care of textual references.. Perfect paintings of him as mentioned in texts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following are the relevant verses [(from Bharatiweb.com) from the DhyAnam](http://www.bharatiweb.com/wp-content/uploads/Rama-Raksha-Stotram-Eng-v1.pdf):

> dhyaayet aajaanubaahum dhruta shara dhanusham **baddha
>   padmaasanastham** |
>  peetam vaaso vasaanam nava kamala dala spardhi
>   netram prasannam |
>  vaamaankaarooDha seetaa mukha kamala
>   milallochanam neeradaabham |
>  naanaalankaaradeeptam
>   dadhatamurujaTaa manDanam raamachandram ||

The [Hindupedia.com translate](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Sri_Rama_Raksha_Stotram)s these verses as follows:

> I meditate on that Ramachandra, whose arms reach up to his thighs, Who
>   carries bow and arrows, **who sits in a lotus pose**, Who is dressed
>   in yellow cloths, who has eyes like the petals of newly opened lotus
>   flower, Who is always pleasant looking, who is the colour of the black
>   cloud, Whose sight is fixed on the lotus eyes of Sita, sitting on his
>   left thigh,  And who shines in various decorations and who has a
>   matted hair around his face

"Baddha PadmAsthanam" means the legs are "locked" in that posture. If he was sitting in Baddha PadmAsan posture then probably it would have been said something like "Baddha Padmasane sthithAm" or something similar.

See [from here](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=baddha&direct=au) the various meanings for the word "Baddha" which are applicable here like joined, folded, locked etc.

To be doubly sure that what I am saying is correct I checked other DhyAna Slokas for Sri RAma.

For one RAma Mantra found in the Tantras, the following is the DhyAnam:

> kAlAmbhodhara kantikantamnisham virAsanAdhyasinam mudrAm
>   jyAnamayim dadhAm maparam hastAmnujam jAnuni |
>  SitAm pArshvagatAm
>   saroruha karAm vidyunnibhAm
>  rAghvam pashyantam mukutAnga
>   dAdivividhAkalpojjvalAngam bhaje ||

The meaning is:

> The complexion of the deity is like that of the color of clouds,
>   darkish is the complexion, exteremely soft is the body of RAmachandra
>   and he is seated in VirAsana posture. **On one hand he is showing JyAnamudrA and
>   the other hand is placed on the thigh.** Situated at his side is
>   SitAdevi, who's holding in her hand a lotus, and who's complexion is
>   like that of thunderbolt. RAmachandra is looking at SitAdevi and his
>   body is decked with dazzling jewels and a crown made of jewels.

So, he has two hands only.

Comment: Ok hope it solves ur problem? :) @ShivamNer

Comment: Yes. It does justify the point that he has 2 hands & not 4 in dhyan mantra :)